# Pyrophoric nature of Raney Nickel

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am about to do a hydrogenation lab, and a, struggling with how to prepare my Raney Nickel so it does not spontaneously ignite during my lab. Most websites say to just submerge it in water– is this correct?

Comment: IT won't catch fire when wet, but it might not work either. If you need it to be dry, use a vacuum line and then fill the vessel with nitrogen. The dry product will catch fire very rapidly if you allow any air into the mixture.

Comment: You also need to be careful with your residues. Do not pull air through them on a filter, they will catch fire if they dry out. Keep them under water in a sealed jar labelled for disposal

Comment: **Please speak to a supervisor or a demonstrator who has been trained in the use of RaNi.** The amount of help you can get over the Internet is very limited.